# Automatically wraps div under if there is not enough space

Tags: html, css

I am trying create a two column layout using divs.
The parent div is X pixel, then it has too child div each takes a certain % of the parent's width.

I want the div2 to wrap under div1 when I reduce the width of the browser without using javascript.

From:

---

### |  Div 1  | Div 2 |

### to

### |  Div 1  |

### |  Div 2  |

This is what I have so far, what should I do to achieve this?

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="width:200px; margin-top: 30px; border: 1px solid green; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="background-color:red; width:100px; float:left;" > 
    test  
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:yellow;">
    test2 
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to float all of the `div` elements and also set a `min-width` for each to force them to wrap at a certain threshold.

Comment: Either float all left or use display:inline-block. also, you'll regret using inline css later, best to use in header.

Comment: @trnelson I tried float all three divs to the left and set min-width, but it still only truncates the div when there is not enough space though.

Comment: I would imagine you need a width on both divs. If there is no width it will get smaller and smaller before it wraps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to float the two divs.

**CSS**

```
.container div {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div>test1</div>
    <div>test2</div>
</div>
```

Here's a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/occursys/6vdc63b9/)**.

Comment: For future visitors to this question, specifying a min-width really brings it all together, imo.

Comment: or use Bootstrap, or any other responsive front end framework instead of reinventing the wheel, just saying.